# How to set datapicker in focus of textbox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

How to set datatimepicker in window form application of c sharp .net. When i am focusing that date textbox my datetimepicker control is shown and after click on that particular date in the that date put on myformatted output in show in text box.I am use simple datetimepicker control.

I am only use datetimepicker control in window form application of c#.net

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far? Or do you expect us to write this for you?

Comment: cant understand a thing

Comment: what are using again datetimepicker or textbox with monthpicker?

Comment: DateTimePicker control. Thanks

Comment: r u using any jquery, can you please edit your question to show us what u have done so far?

Comment: So you have a Datepicker, the user focuses on it and selects a date. Is there something wrong with the date it gives you?

Comment: @GopeshSharma This is WinForms, there won't be any jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `ValueChanged` Event in `dateTimePicker` to do that easily.

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   textBox1.Text = YourFormatedMethod(dateTimePicker1.Text);
}

private string YourFormatedMethod(string selectedDate)
{
  // Your implementation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use databinding:

Place this in form load:

```
//textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", dateTimePicker1, "Text");
//or...
Binding b = new Binding("Text", dateTimePicker1, "Value",true);
b.Format += new ConvertEventHandler(b_Format);
textBox1.DataBindings.Add(b);
```

Then the b_Format handler:

```
private void b_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
{
    //some checking you might want to do...

    e.Value = //your formatting here.
}
```

Comment: No its not work when i am enter in text box then open my datatimepicker

Comment: maybe i got it wrong but....you are asking for click on datetimepicker date and formatt that date to be displayed on textbox right?

Answer (score 0):

```
      // date time picker event code
      private void dtpfromdate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
          dtpfromdate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;

          //here we can select our desired format.
          dtpfromdate.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
          txtfromdate.Text = dtpfromdate.CustomFormat;

          //assign the datetime picker value to textbox.
          txtfromdate.Text = dtpfromdate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 private void dateTimePickerBillDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime pickdt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerBillDate.Text);
            maskedtxtBillDate.Text = pickdt.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: you can add explanation to your code to help understand others.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.